# Create Neo4j database dump with JQAssistant

Tags: neo4j, jqassistant

I want to create a dump of the database that JQAssistant creates with a scan. So far i have tried to do this with the integrated server and by connecting jqassistant to a running database.

The problem with the integrated database is that i can't access a shell and therefore i don't know how i could create the dump.

Connecting to the running database also didn't work. I assume the problem here is the encryption, my server is running local and trying to connect to it with

```
jqassistant.sh scan -f my-project.jar -storeUri bolt://localhost:7687 -storeUsername neo4j -storePassword secret
```

which is the example from the [jqa tutorial](https://101.jqassistant.org/setting-up-a-team-server/index.html)  throws the error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
```

so i assume i can't connect without ssl encryption.

I am using Neo4j server 3.5.15 and JQAssistant Commandline Tool version 1.9 which uses an integrated Neo4j 3.5.14 server.

If you can give me an new idea how to create a data dump out of the scan or how to fix one of the two given problems i would appreciate that a lot!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can connect without ssl encryption using the                                     <encryption>false</encryption>
configuration in the store section. The mentioned jqa tutorial has this as a comment. Or you leave encryption on and configure trust of certificates and/or certificates as described in steps 5 and 6 in the jQAssistant Maven Plugin section.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out a way to export the database with the commandline tool, but with the maven plugin. If you setup a maven project and include jqassistant as a plugin it offers you the option "export-database" which creates a Cypher script.